# Query to send mail to mutliple users with their correspoing tickets

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table which has a list of ticket owners and and tickets which are assigned to them which are of high priority.

For ex:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7HBM.png)

I need to send mail from sql server using sp_send_dbmail to John with all the tickets assigned to him in a single mail. This is a huge table so I want send mails to users with their assigned tickets in single mail instead of sending one mail per ticket.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick google search would give you all the information you need:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190307.aspx

This page tells you exactly what you need to know.

Comment: yes am aware of that. I know the process to send from sp_send_dbmail. But I need a query to send mail to the users with all of the tickets assigned to them in a single mail rather than one mail per ticket.

Comment: then you need to post what you have tried so far in your question, and i will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick...

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--sample of your tickets table
CREATE TABLE #Tickets(
    TicketId INT IDENTITY, 
    TicketOwner VARCHAR(100),
    TicketDetails VARCHAR(MAX)
    )
;

--some sample values
INSERT INTO #Tickets(
    TicketOwner, 
    TicketDetails
    ) 
VALUES
    ('John', 'This is the first ticket'), 
    ('John', 'This is the second ticket'), 
    ('Jeremy', 'This is the third ticket')
;

--gets the dense_rank so you can iterate through the list of distinct users
SELECT  
     TicketId, 
     TicketOwner, 
     TicketDetails, 
     DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TicketOwner) AS RowNum
INTO #Temp
FROM #Tickets
ORDER BY TicketOwner, TicketId
;

--holds the details of each email
DECLARE 
    @RowNum INT = (SELECT MAX(RowNum) FROM #Temp),
    @MySubject VARCHAR(100) = '',
    @MyBody VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
;

--iterate through distinct TicketOwnders by using the dense rank value above
WHILE @RowNum > 0
BEGIN
    --assign variables
    SELECT  @MySubject = TicketOwner + '''s tickets:',
            @MyBody = @MyBody + 'Ticket #' + CAST(TicketId AS VARCHAR(10)) + ': ' + TicketDetails + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)
    FROM #Temp
    WHERE RowNum = @RowNum
    ;

    --send mail
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @recipients = 'jgiaco@fanatics.com',
        @subject = @MySubject,
        @body = @MyBody
    ;

    SET @RowNum = @RowNum - 1;
    SET @MyBody = '';
    SET @MySubject = '';
END
;
```